# LINQ query to join lists

Tags: c#, linq

I need help to write  complex linq query

get a list of number of vehicles from each country where we have more than one vehicle type from that country sorted by the number of vehicles ascending

These are the lists

```
 private readonly IReadOnlyList<InventoryItem> vehicles = new List<InventoryItem>
    {
        new InventoryItem(new Car("Ford", "Focus", 115000), 20),
        new InventoryItem(new Car("BMW", "7 Series", 425000), 12),
        new InventoryItem(new Car("Lexus", "ES", 300000), 5),
        new InventoryItem(new Plane("Boeing", "747", 2200000000), 2),
        new InventoryItem(new Car("Nissan", "Micra", 90000), 27),
        new InventoryItem(new Plane("Airbus", "A380", 4150000000), 1)
    };

    private readonly IReadOnlyList<Company> companies = new List<Company>
    {
        new Company("Ford", "US"),
        new Company("BMW", "Germany"),
        new Company("Lexus", "Japan"),
        new Company("Nissan", "Japan"),
        new Company("Boeing", "US"),
        new Company("Airbus", "France")
    };
```

Output should be like

```
| Country | Quantity |
| US      | 22       |
| Japan   | 32       |
```

Comment: can you give whole model classes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below query which output as you required

```
var result = from vehicle in vehicles
            join company in companies on vehicle.Item.Name equals company.Name
            group new {vehicle, company} by company.Country into countryGroup
            select new { Country = countryGroup.Key, Quantity = countryGroup.Sum(c => c.vehicle.Quantity)};
```

The output of above query for your input is

```
| Country | Quantity |
| US      | 22       |
| Germany | 12       |
| Japan   | 32       |
| France  | 1        |
```

Since you have not posted your model classes so I have created mine which are as follows :

```
public interface IItem
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    string Modal {get;set;}
    long Power {get;set;}
}

public class Car : IItem
{
    public Car(string name, string modal, long power)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Modal = modal;
        this.Power = power;
    }

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Modal {get;set;}
    public long Power {get;set;}
}

public class Plane : IItem
{
    public Plane(string name, string modal, long power)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Modal = modal;
        this.Power = power;
    }

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Modal {get;set;}
    public long Power {get;set;}
}

public class InventoryItem
{
    public InventoryItem(IItem item, int quantity)
    {
        this.Item = item;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public IItem Item {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get;set;}
}

public class Company
{
    public Company(string name, string country)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Country = country;
    }

    public string Country {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

You can check the live fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JiqhRb).

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    internal class Item
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public long Price { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Car: Item
    {
        internal Car(string brand, string model, long price)
        {
            Brand = brand;
            Model = model;
            Price = price;
        }
    }

    internal class Plane : Item
    {
        internal Plane(string brand, string model, long price)
        {
            Brand = brand;
            Model = model;
            Price = price;
        }
    }
}

 internal class Company
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        internal Company(string brand, string country)
        {
            Brand = brand;
            Country = country;
        }
    }


  internal class InventoryItem
    {
        public InventoryItem(Item item, int count)
        {
            Item = item;
            Count = count;
        }

        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

 internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             IReadOnlyList<InventoryItem> vehicles = new List<InventoryItem>
                {
                new InventoryItem(new Car("Ford", "Focus", 115000), 20),
                new InventoryItem(new Car("BMW", "7 Series", 425000), 12),
                new InventoryItem(new Car("Lexus", "ES", 300000), 5),
                new InventoryItem(new Plane("Boeing", "747", 2200000000), 2),
                new InventoryItem(new Car("Nissan", "Micra", 90000), 27),
                new InventoryItem(new Plane("Airbus", "A380", 4150000000), 1)
                };

            IReadOnlyList<Company> companies = new List<Company>
            {
                new Company("Ford", "US"),
                new Company("BMW", "Germany"),
                new Company("Lexus", "Japan"),
                new Company("Nissan", "Japan"),
                new Company("Boeing", "US"),
                new Company("Airbus", "France")
            };

            var countryCount = companies.Join(vehicles, i => i.Brand, j => j.Item.Brand, (i, j) => new { i.Country, j.Count }).GroupBy(k => k.Country).Select(group=> new { Country = group.Key, Total = group.Sum(count => count.Count) });
            foreach(var group in countryCount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Country : { group.Country}, count { group.Total }");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```